# Remove an item at a specific Index from a dynamic String Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, dynamic-arrays

I have a dynamic string array and I have populated it with some dynamic values using ReDim etc. I would like to delete an item from the string array at a specific position. I have read about using a Where condition using System.Linq but can't really get a proper answer to this. Any suggestions?

```
Dim dynamic() as String
...
Redim dynamic(2)
..
dynamic(0) = Apple
dynamic(1) = Banana
dynamic(2) = Orange
..

dynamic(i).Remove... etc?
```

Comment: You cannot remove an item from an array. You need to create a new array and skip copying the index which you don't want.

Comment: Use a List(of String) instad of an array and you can use LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there is technically no way to remove an element from an array.  The only way to modify the number of elements in the array is to create a whole new array and copy the contents from the one to the other.  There are more convenient methods you can use to do it, but in the end, that's what they are actually doing for you, just behind the scenes.

If you are going to be doing a lot of that kind of thing, I would recommend using the `List(Of String)` class rather than a `String` array.  As others have pointed out, the `List(Of T)` class is specifically designed to make those kinds of dynamic functions more simple.  If, you ever need the list as an array, you can very easily (and efficiently) convert it to an array like this:

```
Dim myList As New List(Of String)()
myList.Add("Apple")
myList.Add("Banana")
myList.Add("Orange")
myList.RemoveAt(1)
Dim myArray() As String = myList.ToArray()
```

However, if you really must have it as an array, LINQ does make it a bit easier.  By importing the LINQ namespace, many new LINQ extension methods will be added to arrays (and any other list or enumerable objects).  For instance, you could use LINQ's `Except` method, like this:

```
Dim dynamic() As String = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"}
dynamic = dynamic.Except({"Banana"}).ToArray()
```

Notice that the `Except` method returns an enumerable object, but not an array.  To convert it to an array, you'll need to additionally call LINQ's `ToArray` method, as in the above example.  That above example removes the string `"Banana"` from the middle of the array.  If, however, you don't know the value and you just want to remove it by index, LINQ doesn't provide a way to filter by index like that.  You could still use the `Except` method like this, though:

```
Dim dynamic() As String = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"}
dynamic = dynamic.Except({dynamic(1)}).ToArray()
```

You may be wondering why I put the curly brackets around the parameter passed to the `Except` method.  I did that because the `Except` method actually takes a list of parameters (`IEnumerable`, to be specific).  Since array's implement `IEnumerable` (as well as `IList`, by the way), I just wrapped the parameter in an array before passing it to the method.  The interesting upshot of this is that if you have multiple items to remove, you could do them all in one command, like this:

```
Dim dynamic() As String = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"}
dynamic = dynamic.Except({"Apple", "Banana"}).ToArray()
```

Comment: That is actually quite helpful. Going to give it a try. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly with arrays. But you can do this:

```
Dim tmp = New List(Of string)(dynamic)
tmp.RemoveAt(index)
dynamic = tmp.ToArray()
```

Comment: I'll give it a try...Will get back to you.